# PHP octet-stream media get file extension

Tags: php

I have a `"application/octet-stream"` post being made from an iOS device. That post either contains video or an image that is in binary. I have figured out how to grab the contents of the post using:

```
$postdata = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

My question is their a way to know what the file extension of the file is? I need to save it in respective folders either the video or image folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should look at the [Fileinfo](http://php.net/manual/en/ref.fileinfo.php) functions, specifically `finfo_buffer`, you can use it to find out the MIME type of your string `$postdata` to know whether it's an image or video.